# Understanding generics and polymorphism

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren’t Java’s generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

```
public abstract class AbstractServerSession<E extends AbstractPacket> {
[...]
packet = (E) PacketFactory.getPacket(packetClazz);
```

I get this error that IMHO makes no sense:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from AbstractPacket to E`

How he cannot convert if I explicitly stated that `E` is a child of `AbstractPacket`?

I can add a cast

```
packet = (E) PacketFactory.getPacket(packetClazz);
```

but then of course I get this warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from AbstractPacket to E
```

So what is `<E extends AbstractPacket>` for?

EDIT: as requested

```
public static final AbstractPacket getPacket(Class<? extends AbstractPacket> clazz)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do class `PacketFactory` and its method `getPacket` look like?

Comment: I don't see the connect between `AbstractServerSession` and `PacketFactory`. You have shown two completely disparate pieces of code. There are no conclusions to draw.

Comment: From the warning you can infer that getPacket() returns AbstractPacket: *Type mismatch: cannot convert **from AbstractPacket to E***. I'll put the prototype. Also I don't see this as an exact duplicate of the other question. He's using different types for the generics and here I'm casting a return value.

Comment: Ok I see why now based on the duplicate, thanks Marko. I voted to close my own question, just feels weird :)

Comment: Why did you vote to close your own question? Just delete it...

Answer (score 0):

> but then of course I get this warning:
>   Type safety: Unchecked cast from AbstractPacket to E

I think the warning makes sense since E type can't be decided at compiling time, but it didn't impact on your running.

Comment: E type can't be decided at compiling time -> not totally true, it can be bound to children of AbstractPacket.